# I need to use variable, loop outside?

Tags: php, variables, for-loop

I have a simple loop

```
for($i=0;$i<10;$i++)
{
    $sample =  "";
    $sample    .= $i.", ";
}
echo $sample;
```

this outputs:

> 9,

How can I get this output instead?

> 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9,

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`$sample =  "";` initializes the variable to an empty string. Move that *before* your loop.

With that statement inside the loop, you're re-initializing `$sample` on each iteration. That's why you only see the last value.

```
$sample =  "";                 // here
for($i=0;$i<10;$i++)
{
                               // not here
    $sample    .= $i.", ";
}
echo $sample;
```